# Why $P(\bigcap_{n\geq 1}A_n) = P(|X_n - X| \geq \varepsilon , \forall n \geq 1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, proof-explanation, sequence-of-function

Let $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables that converges almost surely to the variable X. Prove that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability.

**My attempt**

Let $\varepsilon >0$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let us define the events $$A_n = \bigcup_{k\geq n}(|X_k - X| \geq \varepsilon)$$

This sequence is such that $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $(|X_n - X|\geq \varepsilon ) \subset A_n$, then $P(|X_n - X|\geq \varepsilon ) \leq P(A_n)$, where $P$ is the probability measure of the sets. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|X_n - X|\geq \varepsilon ) &\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}P(A_n)\\ &=P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n\right)\\ &=P\left(\bigcap_{n \geq 1}A_n\right)\\ &= P(|X_n -X|\geq \varepsilon, \forall n\geq 1)\\ &= P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n \neq X\right)\\
&= 0
\end{align*}

My question is this: why $P(\bigcap_{n\geq 1}A_n) = P(|X_n - X| \geq \varepsilon, \forall n\geq 1)$

That is, how to justify this step of the proof? Or, what is the need to do this step?

In order for me to prove that these probabilities are equal, I think I should prove that $\bigcap_{n\geq 1}A_n = \{ |X_n - X| \geq \varepsilon, \forall n\geq 1\}$, however this is not true in general as can be seen in the comments. How can I do that? I would be very grateful if someone can help me understand this part.

Comment: I think you can only prove $P(\bigcap_{n\geq 1}A_n) \ge P(|X_n - X| \geq \varepsilon, \forall n \ge 1) $. The left-hand side is the probability that $|X_n - X| \ge \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: Since $X_n \to X$ as, $P(\cap_n A_n) = 0$, so the equality holds, but it does not hold in general. Take $X_n$ to be iid. taking values $0,1$ with equal probability, $X=0$ and $\epsilon ={1 \over 2}$. Then $P \cap_{n \ge 1} A_n = 1$ but $P[|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon, n \ge 1] = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you mean that, in general, $\bigcap_{n \geq 1}A_n \neq \{|X_n - X| \geq \varepsilon, \forall n \geq 1\}$?

Comment: @Inquirer Yes, in general there is a difference between something happening infinitely often rather than always (or even eventually always).

Comment: @Inquirer I do not understand your question.

Comment: @copper.hat Since, in general $\bigcap_{n\geq 1}A_n \neq \{|X_n - X| \geq \varepsilon, \forall n \geq 1\}$, I think that one of the two contentions holds. What is the contention that is satisfied?

Comment: @Inquirer Sorry, I still do not understand which contentions you are referring to. If you assume that $X_n \to X$ as, then the equation is true and both sides are zero.

Comment: @copper.hat To make it easier to understand, I have edited my question.

Comment: Hint: maybe look at Fatou's Lemma again :)

Comment: @JosephDoob I really don't understand how to apply Fatou's lemma in this case, can you give me more details please?

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate step in your derivation is plain false. The correct one is the following.
$$
\bigcap_{n\geq 1} A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \bigcup_{k\geq n}\{|X_k - X| \geq \varepsilon\} = \{\forall n\geq 1, \exists k\geq n, |X_k - X| \geq \varepsilon\} = \{X_n \not \to X\}
$$